How to save a conection websocket in rust?
I wrote this code in typescript and now I'm migrating it to rust, it's very simple, if you receive a message with the "main" value, it saves the connection in the appWebClient variable, and all messages are now sent to this appWebClient.
let appWebClient: any


const createWebServer = () => {
  const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 2004 }, () => {
    console.log('server started')
  })

  wss.on('connection', ws => {
    ws.on('message', data => {
      let main = JSON.parse(data)

      if (main.event == 'main') {
        appWebClient = ws
        return
      }

      let newData = main as unknown as WsBotEvents

      appWebClient.send(JSON.stringify(newData))
    })
  })

  wss.on('listening', () => {
    console.log('server listening on port 2004')
  })
}

Already in the rust code, the only thing I managed to do was connect the websocket server,
In my rust code, the only thing I managed to do was connect the websocket server, when I try to save the connection if it is "main", it gives me this error: use of moved value: ws_sender
value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
Here the full error:
 error[E0382]: use of moved value: `ws_sender`
  --> src\main.rs:72:53
   |
50 | let (ws_sender, mut ws_receiver) = ws_stream.split();
   | --------- move occurs because `ws_sender` has type `SplitSink<WebSocketStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>, tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Message>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
53 | while let Some(Ok(Message::Text(data))) = ws_receiver.next().await {
   | -------------------------------------------------- ---------------- inside of this loop
...
72 | *main_ws = Some(ws_sender);
   | ^^^^^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    tokio::spawn(ws());

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}


async fn ws() {
    let url = "127.0.0.1:2004";
    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(url)
        .await
        .expect("Failed to bind address");

    println!("WebSocket server running on {}", url);

    let main_ws: Arc<Mutex<Option<SplitSink<WebSocketStream<TcpStream>, Message>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));
    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        println!("WebSocket connection accepted");

        let main_ws_clone = main_ws.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            if let Ok(ws_stream) = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(stream).await {
                println!("New WebSocket connection established");

                let (ws_sender, mut ws_receiver) = ws_stream.split();

                // Loop para receber mensagens do cliente
                while let Some(Ok(Message::Text(data))) = ws_receiver.next().await {

                    let mut main_ws =  main_ws_clone.lock().unwrap();

                    
                    // Trate as mensagens recebidas aqui
                    let mut new_data: Value = serde_json::Value::Null;

                    match serde_json::from_str(&data) {

                        Ok(value) => {

                            new_data = value;
                            let event = new_data["event"].as_str().unwrap_or("");
                            
                            match event {
                                "main" => {

                                   
                                    *main_ws = Some(ws_sender);
                                    println!("WebSocket connection registered as main");

                                }
                                _ => {}
                            }
                        }
                        Err(_) => todo!(),
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

I've tried everything, but every alternative gives me a different error

The problem is that when a connection sends multiple "main" events the ws_sender will be moved multiple times, but that's not possible. You can ensure that it's only moved once, for example with an Option:
async fn ws() {
    let url = "127.0.0.1:2004";
    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind(url)
        .await
        .expect("Failed to bind address");

    println!("WebSocket server running on {}", url);

    let main_ws: Arc<Mutex<Option<SplitSink<WebSocketStream<TcpStream>, Message>>>> =
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(None));
    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
        println!("WebSocket connection accepted");

        let main_ws_clone = main_ws.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            if let Ok(ws_stream) = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(stream).await {
                println!("New WebSocket connection established");

                let (ws_sender, mut ws_receiver) = ws_stream.split();
                let mut ws_sender = Some(ws_sender);

                // Loop para receber mensagens do cliente
                while let Some(Ok(Message::Text(data))) = ws_receiver.next().await {
                    let mut main_ws = main_ws_clone.lock().unwrap();

                    match serde_json::from_str(&data) {
                        Ok(new_data) => {
                            let event = new_data["event"].as_str().unwrap_or("");

                            match event {
                                "main" => {
                                    if let ws_sender @ Some(_) = ws_sender.take() {
                                        *main_ws = ws_sender;
                                    }
                                    println!("WebSocket connection registered as main");
                                }
                                _ => {}
                            }
                        }
                        Err(_) => todo!(),
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

